# Compare dates in different formats in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I have 2 dates to compare in Javascript i.e. "2019-05-26" and "26-05-2019". What will be the best approach to achieve the same?

I tried below and gives me true value, but not sure if that is the right way to do it.

```
Date("26-05-2019") === Date("2019-05-26");
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"but not sure if that is the right way to do it"* No, not reliably cross-browser. See the linked question's answers for what to do instead.

Comment: `"26-05-2019".split('-').reverse().join('-') === "2019-05-26"`. In this case, you don't need to have two `Date` objects.